# Delphi-docking form hides panel

Tags: delphi

I have a problem that docking form hides some other components inside of panel.

This is simple example of my problem: I have Panel1 with DockSite set to True. Inside Panel1 is Panel2. Panel2 alignts to client (Align=alClient). Inside Panel2 is memo field that is also aligned to client. It overlaps the entire Panel1.
I have another form (Form2) that I want to dock to Panel1. But it overlaps entire Panel1 and hides memo filed. I want to overlap only part of Panel1 (width of the form) and move Panel2 to the rigth or to te left.

Main form:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;

end.


object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 333
  ClientWidth = 754
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 15
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 288
    Top = 271
    Width = 153
    Height = 41
    Caption = 'Show dockable form'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 729
    Height = 257
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    DockSite = True
    TabOrder = 1
    object Panel2: TPanel
      Left = 1
      Top = 1
      Width = 727
      Height = 255
      Align = alClient
      Caption = 'Panel2'
      TabOrder = 0
      ExplicitLeft = 360
      ExplicitTop = 8
      ExplicitWidth = 337
      ExplicitHeight = 241
      object Memo1: TMemo
        Left = 1
        Top = 1
        Width = 725
        Height = 253
        Align = alClient
        Lines.Strings = (
          'Memo1')
        TabOrder = 0
        ExplicitWidth = 216
        ExplicitHeight = 144
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Docking form:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.

object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 103
  ClientWidth = 273
  Color = clBtnFace
  DragKind = dkDock
  DragMode = dmAutomatic
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 15
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 22
    Top = 24
    Width = 227
    Height = 45
    Caption = 'Dockable form'
    DragKind = dkDock
    DragMode = dmAutomatic
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -33
    Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
  end
end
```

Comment: Based on your description it seems that both your `Panel2` and your `Form2`  get aligned with `alClient` alignment at the same time. But when aligning multiple windows/controls in same container/component only one of them can use `alClient` alignment. rest of the controls/windows need to use other alignment types like `alTop`, `alBottom`, `alLeft` or `alRight` in order to make sure they are not overlapping each other. So try changing the alignment of your` Panel2` when you drop the `Form2` on your `Panel1` component.

Comment: It didn't help. Form is still overlapping 'Panel2'. Tried to set form and panel alignment to 'alLeft' and 'alRight'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamics soon become difficult to master with changing dock sites and alignment changes, but I think the following will do what you ask for.

Change the hierarchy of `Form1` to the following and note that `Panel2` and `Memo1` both are childs of `Panel1`. `Panel2` will act as the docking target. I have set `Panel2.Width` to 8, to have a visual area where to drop `Form2`. Here are the essential properties:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  object Button1: TButton
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    object Panel2: TPanel
      Width = 8
      Align = alRight
      Caption = 'Panel2'
      DockSite = True
      OnDockDrop = Panel2DockDrop
      OnDockOver = Panel2DockOver
      OnUnDock = Panel2UnDock
    end
    object Memo1: TMemo
      Align = alClient
    end
  end
end
```

When `Form2` is dragged over `Panel2` the `OnDockOver` event is triggered. `Panel2` sets its width to half the width of `Panel1`, which in turn reduces the `Memo1` width with the same amount. (Change as you need)

```
procedure TForm1.Panel2DockOver(Sender: TObject; Source: TDragDockObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Panel2.Width := Panel1.Width div 2;
end;
```

<strike>When `Form2` is dropped on `Panel2`, the `DockRect` of the form is set to the rect of `Panel2`.</strike>

```
procedure TForm1.Panel2DockDrop(Sender: TObject; Source: TDragDockObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Source.DockRect := Rect(Panel2.Width, Panel2.Top, Panel2.Width, Panel2.Height);
end;
```

When `Form2` is undocked from `Panel2` it reduces its width to the 8 pixels, which again widen the `Memo1` to its original width.

```
procedure TForm1.Panel2UnDock(Sender: TObject; Client: TControl; NewTarget: TWinControl;
  var Allow: Boolean);
begin
  Panel2.Width := 8;
end;
```

Here's the complete `.dfm` of `Form1`:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 333
  ClientWidth = 425
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = True
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 15
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 120
    Top = 284
    Width = 153
    Height = 41
    Caption = 'Show dockable form'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 400
    Height = 257
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 1
    object Panel2: TPanel
      Left = 391
      Top = 1
      Width = 8
      Height = 255
      Align = alRight
      Caption = 'Panel2'
      DockSite = True
      TabOrder = 0
      OnDockDrop = Panel2DockDrop
      OnDockOver = Panel2DockOver
      OnUnDock = Panel2UnDock
      ExplicitLeft = 394
    end
    object Memo1: TMemo
      Left = 1
      Top = 1
      Width = 390
      Height = 255
      Align = alClient
      Lines.Strings = (
        'Memo1')
      TabOrder = 1
      ExplicitWidth = 725
      ExplicitHeight = 253
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

[image]